# Django tabular input form (user can key in data into table)

Tags: django

I attempt to create a tabular input form. User can key in data into the table cells. The table should have 100 rows. The following is an illustration of the end goal.

[image: sample table]

However, if such table is not possible, a suggestion to create the following table is also welcomed!
[image: sample table 2]

This is what I have tried:

**forms.py**

```
class SampleInputForm(forms.Form):
    x = forms.FloatField()
    y = forms.FloatField()
```

**views.py**

```
class ToolView(View):
    def get(self, request):

        table_rows = 10
        sample_form_set_factory = formset_factory(SampleInputForm, extra = table_rows)
        sample_form_set = sample_form_set_factory()

        context = {
            'sample_form' : sample_form_set,
        }
        return render(request, 'tools/tools.html', context)
```

**html file**

```
{% csrf_token %}
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Input</th>
            <th>Output</th>
        </tr>
        {{sample_form}}
    </table>
</form>
```

However, this attempt does not form a table. The Y input field is displayed below the X, hence not forming a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formset_factory is iterable , so in template you can do this

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Input</th>
                <th>Output</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for form in sample_form %}
            <tr>
                <th>
                    {{ form.x }}
                </th>
                <th>
                    {{ form.y }}
                </th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: same result as my current attempt